# Why is my object being treated as a ql object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to use Firebase.Firestore.set() with an object, I get an error saying "(FirebaseError): Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom ql object"

I'm using Firebase in a React class, and I tried creating the object right in the function and defining it separately as shown below:

```js
if (authUser) {
        const userObj = {
          name: authUser.displayName,
          uid: authUser.uid,
          email: authUser.email,
          emailVerified: authUser.emailVerified,
          providerData: authUser.providerData
        }
        this.db.collection("users").doc(authUser.uid).set(userObj, { merge: true })
    }
```

Comment: can you console log the value of authUser?

Comment: @andresmijares When I console log authUser, I get 'Q' with the correct object properties inside it instead of the normal {...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the `providerData` (which comes from the identity provider) contains data of a type that Firestore can't handle. To fix this problem, either don't store the provider data, or convert it into a compatible type with this hack:

```
providerData: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(authUser.providerData))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to copy an instance of an object, (i guess is a graphql object) and firebase does not support that, you need to use primitive values. Make sure you copy strings on all the properties instead of pointers to the class.